# Why is my configuration manager disabled in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I just started working on a new project and I can't set the build action to Debug/Release. This is a huge problem!

I have another solution on my system that, when opened, allows me to change the solution configuration. So it must have something to do with this specific solution?

Comment: Does the project file (.csproj, .fsproj, .vbproj, ...) have Debug/Release configurations defined?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

(from http://www.gregcons.com/KateBlog/HowDoIMakeADebugBuild.aspx, which includes screenshots)

bring up Tools, Options, and go to the General section under Projects and Solutions. Find "Show advanced build configurations" and check it.

Comment: Indeed. A total discoverability fail. And I blogged that three years ago :-)

Comment: I've been down this road before and I still had to google it to figure it out. Very frustrating. Thanks.

Comment: AWESOME THANKS KATE HIDDEN GEMS

Comment: On a fresh Windows 10 Pro install, with a fresh Visual Studio 2010 install, I just tried this and it did not work. I actually found this solution on my own and was surprised it did not work. Then I searched and found your solution here. If I figure it out, I'll post a reply.

Comment: Here is the solution to my issue above: If you're using an Express version of VS, turn on the Expert Settings (Tools->Settings->Expert Settings). Then the solution here works.

Answer (score 2):

The right solution is to:

1. Tools, Options
2. Click General section under Projects and Solutions.
3. Check Show advanced build configurations.

You should see the solution configuration drop-down will be enabled

Comment: I'm not going to argue, but how is this different from the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

From [a Google search](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vstsstart/thread/ffdd074d-0b1f-4960-b42f-e5879ff11d7a)

```
Tools | Customize from the menu.

In the Build section, drag the "Solution  Configuration" item from the list
on the right to the build toolbar.  You might also want to drag the "Platform
Configuration" item as well. The Configuration Manager itself is available
from the drop-down list of either of those controls.  Also check
Tools|Customize|Toolbars to make sure that the Build toolbar is visible.
```

Comment: Configuration manager is just outright Disabled for this project.   I even added "Configuration Manager" to the top menu bar --> It appears Greyed-out.  ???

Comment: Till now, I guess, It is not available for Website templates projects. It needed to be converted to Solutions / Project with csproj files to enable these configurations. @MattH.