# Visual Studio 2010 professional Configuration manager missing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-lightswitch

My Configuration manager in Visual Studio 2010 is missing:

http://screencast.com/t/ksnE9q8EX7W

I found another question on stackoverflow:

[Why is my configuration manager disabled in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074272/why-is-my-configuration-manager-disabled-in-visual-studio-2010)

But my settings are correct:

http://screencast.com/t/qXHz0RWqnZ

I am using it with a LightSwitch project, but I noticed that I have the same problem with other projects!

Comment: I found it allready :)... It was in a toolbar! - http://screencast.com/t/hKsTqcfHspch

Answer (score 0):

I found it allready :)... It was in a toolbar! - screencast.com/t/hKsTqcfHspch