# VB NET class is recognized in VS, but I get a 'Type is Undefined' error on build

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am working on a VB NET project and had the strangest thing happen.

I created a class file(just like a dozen or so I have already created). I wrote in the code to access it. The autocomplete found the class, filled it in and colored it blue, just as it should.

But, when I run the app, I get a type is undefined error.

There is nothing in the class yet. And there is really no code to post..it is as straight forward as I described.

I tried restarting VS; Deleting and recreating the class; Deleting the class and creating a new one with a different name.

Is there something in the VB NET configuration I can check to see if it is not being added somewhere?

lee

Ok. I found the problem. I have 2 projects in one solution. They both share some classes that were trying to use my new classes. When I hit F5, both projects are compiled, and since I hadn't shared the classes with the second project, it errored.

So, now my question is changed; How do I specify to only build the specified Startup Project when debugging?

lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click your solution -> properties -> configuration properties and untick everything you don't want to build.

And for your original question, check if build action on that files that don't compile is set to 'compile'

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a 'COnfiguration Properties' on my VS. I have the free VB 2010 version.

Comment: ..and regarding the compile; I can turn that off, but then I have to re-enable it when I want to build that project. It seems to me, that it should be easy to specify only to build the current Startup Project.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not aware of express edition. Can you right click that project you are talking about in solution explorer and select 'build'? And yes, build action has to be set to 'build', was just an idea what may be wrong.

Comment: Thanks. You can select build, but it does not run in the debugger.

Comment: That was, i was talking about: [Solution Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166577.aspx), but i'm not sure if it's available in express edition.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074272/why-is-my-configuration-manager-disabled-in-visual-studio-2010) can help.

Comment: Thanks Milter. It is not the exact solution I was hoping for, but it is managable.