# Why is my configuration manager deploy check box disabled in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, configuration, publish

I am trying to publish my solution to Microsoft Azure in Visual Studio 2017.  In the configuration manager, the Deploy check box is grayed out and I can not put a check mark in it.

I understand a similar question was asked [about the configuration manager being disabled in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074272/why-is-my-configuration-manager-disabled-in-visual-studio-2010)

However, the solution to that post does not work in Visual Studio 2017.  I have tried going to Tools> Options>General and the check box for Show advanced build configurations is already checked.
Please help.

[image: configure manager picture]

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to publish a solution or a specific project within the solution?

Comment: I was trying to publish a project within the solution.  I was not able put a check mark in the check box, but I found a different way to deploy the solution to Microsoft Azure.  I still think it would be nice to know a solution to my problem though.

Answer (score 11):

Not sure if it helps, but in my case, with Win32 app/DLL projects, **Deploy** is enabled against the project, which is configured for remote debugging with deployment:

- in the **Configuration/Debugging** property page of the project, for "Debugger to launch" **Remote Windows Debugger** option selected
- **Deployment Directory** option is configured

[image: remote debugger configuration]

[image: Deploy option enabled]

Comment: It worked for me. Visual Studio 2017 (15.6.0). C++ console application. SDK version: 10.0.16299.0.

Comment: I was tearing my hair out, seemingly same problem in 2019, and then someone else noticed that Configuration Manager was showing the "Debug" configuration but I was setting the remote debugging properties for the "Release" configuration.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to publish my solution to Microsoft Azure in Visual Studio 2017. In the configuration manager, the Deploy check box is grayed out and I can not put a check mark in it.

As far as I know, it would be related to the real **project type** created in your VS.

**Deploy**: If enabled, specifies whether or not the project will be deployed when the Run or Deploy commands are used with the selected solution build configuration. 
This check box only appears for deployable projects. For example, the database project is ok, the .NET MVC project is not. For more details about configuration manager, you could refer to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1hy4dhz(v=vs.100).aspx).

I also have created a simple demo includes .NET MVC project and database project. You could see the database project could be deployed from the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I have seen that link, but I am still not able to put a check mark in the check box.

Comment: Right click solution>Add new project>choose SQL Server>create this project. Then right click solution>Configuration manager>You could see the screenshot as I have showed.